# jQuery load-mouseover on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and have some plug ins installed.  I've been doing so many tests to figure how to improve my site and one of the plug ins called "Autoptimize" kinda messed up the site requests so I deactivated the plug in but it stopped my site logo from working with the mouseover effect. I traced down the issue and found the codes on the theme footer have an extra link "https://cdn.shortpixel.ai" which is what the plug in uses as a server to reduce the load time, but I don't want it. Deactivating the plugin doesn't remove the server link "https://cdn.shortpixel.ai", so I deleted the link myself, but I still can't figure out why the logo is not changing when I hover my mouse over it.

old code with https://cdn.shortpixel.ai

```js
<script>
$('#loadMore').click(function(e){
    $('.tech-none').addClass('tech-flex');
    $(this).fadeOut();
})
$(document).ready(function(){$(".logo img").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
    $(this).attr('srcset','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/footer-logo-1.png');
        $(this).attr('srcset','https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/to_webp,q_glossy,ret_img,w_338/https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1.png 338w, https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_glossy,ret_img,w_300/https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1-300x61.png 300w');
        });
        $(".footer-logo img").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
            $(this).attr('srcset','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/footer-logo-1.png');
                $(this).attr('srcset','https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/to_webp,q_glossy,ret_img,w_338/https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1.png 338w, https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_glossy,ret_img,w_300/https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1-300x61.png 300w');
                });});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the new code after deleting https://cdn.shortpixel.ai

```js
<script>
$('#loadMore').click(function(e){
    $('.tech-none').addClass('tech-flex');
    $(this).fadeOut();
})
$(document).ready(function(){$(".logo img").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
    $(this).attr('srcset','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/footer-logo-1.png');
        $(this).attr('srcset','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1.png 338w, https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1-300x61.png 300w');
        });
        $(".footer-logo img").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
            $(this).attr('srcset','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/logo-hover.png');
            }).mouseout(function(){
                $(this).attr('src','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/footer-logo-1.png');
                $(this).attr('srcset','https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1.png 338w, https://bluediamondautoglass.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/logo-1_01d27e1208cb366b98b7ea9bddd89f38-1-300x61.png 300w');
                });});
</script>
```

(I didn't code this but I can do simple changes and understand a thing or two)

Comment: Do you have any version or source control software?

Comment: Not really, I have access to the cPanel and wordpress backend. @quantumPuter

Comment: It can help you isolate problems like if you use it in the future.

Comment: @quantumPuter which software you think is the best to use ? I see many options.